# How do you swap elements of a struct array in c?

Tags: c++, c, arrays, struct, swap

I've seen the couple other question regarding this topic, but none of the answers have worked for me.

My swapClasses method follows:

```
void swapClasses(struct ClassInfo *p1, struct ClassInfo *p2){
    ClassInfo *temp = p1;

    *p1 = *p2;
    *p2 = *temp;
}
```

But when I execute the code and attempt to add a class that should technically appear first in the array, it is just added to the end. No swapping takes place even though I know that portion of the code executes (tested with a simple print statement). I believe there is something wrong with the way I'm using pointers. Can anyone advise?

Comment: Weird lix of C and C++ there. Since you're using iostreams, you'll have to compile with a C++ compiler. Therefore this question should be tagged C++.

Comment: Yes... It's very frustrating actually. We're supposed to write the program in C, but we apparently needed the cin.getline() function (that portion of the code was already written by my professor). Everything I am supposed to do has to be written in C though. I've added the C++ tag since you suggested it.

Comment: @rphello101 In what sense do you "need" the `cin.getline()` function? You can do the very same thing it does by calling `fgets(buffer, sizeof buffer, stdin)` in C. Also, I suggest you revise pointers, you made a trivial mistake.

Comment: @H2CO3 as I mentioned previously, the portion of the code using cin.getline() was already written. If I had done it myself, I would have written the entire program in c and avoided any problems.

Comment: @rphello101 Ah OK. Well, tell your prof that he's insane. "I would have written the entire program in c and avoided any problems." -- **exactly.**

Answer (score 4):

Getting a pointer to an element in the array won't save that element from being overwritten by a write through another pointer to it. Therefore your swap function is wrong. You should be **copying** the first item into the temporary, like this:

```
void swapClasses(struct ClassInfo *p1, struct ClassInfo *p2){
    ClassInfo temp = *p1;
    *p1 = *p2;
    *p2 = temp;
}
```

Comment: I tried changing the swapClasses as you suggested. Now when I add a class, the old elements of the array are unchanged and the new one I enter is added to the end, but is completely blank... (as seen through the function that prints the array) Any ideas why that is?

Comment: @rphello101 Well there may be other bugs in your code as well, in this case :) I pointed out this problem because this was entirely obvious at first glance, but to be entirely honest: your code is quite long, hard to read (due to the lack of whitespace) and I don't really have the capability to proofread all of it (it's 7AM here).

Comment: For the life of me, I can't find a bug anywhere else. I knew something was going on with pointers and I was hoping your solution was the answer... I've spent the last week struggling with this program. It's due in 2 hours. We'll see if anyone does have the time to help me out...